# ReplaceAll using Java and HTML - Changing colors

Tags: html

I have a java code communicating with an HTML page which should change everything starting with "color" into the color "red". I'm using the function ReplaceAll, I'm not sure if the syntax is the same for strings and colors. Any tips?

```
what I have:
    <td width = 150 bgcolor = "colorstatus">status</td>
    <td width = 150 bgcolor = "colorstack">stack</td>

What I need from what I have:
    <td width = 150 bgcolor = "red">status</td>
    <td width = 150 bgcolor = "red">stack</td>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi! are you trying to make the background red and the <td> element have a width of 150px? If so, your HTML syntax is wrong - please clarify what it is you are trying to output

Comment: what have you tired ? show us some codes. As it stands its unclear what you want. Further provide an [mcve]. (Also are you sure you are talking about `java` and not `javascript` perchance?)

Comment: @O.PJ Are you using it with JSF and manged beans? If this is true, I can send you a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
String replaced = html.replaceAll("\"color.+?\"", "\"red\"");
```

Comment: Indeed, that worked hehe. Thanks a bunch, you're the best!